# Which of these statistics provide information about the location of a dataset?

Tags: probability, statistics

> Which of these statistics provide information about the location of a dataset?

1) Sample Mean 
2) Sample Standard Deviation 
3) Sample Median 
4) Interquantile Range

I'm pretty sure that the sample median provides information about the location of a dataset, but I need also another one, can someone please help me?

Comment: Mean, median, mode and quartiles are measures of location. Standard deviation, range and interquartile range are the measures of dispersion.

Comment: The problem is that I can select just two of them, so two between mean, median and IQR?

Comment: Median and interquantiles

Comment: The sample mean is 0 for any symmetric data set regardless of location so it's a bad measure

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Comment: @orange The interquartile *range* is a measure of dispersion/spread, see the comment by user farruhota. Moreover, whether the data is symmetric or not makes no difference to the fact that any kind of mean is a measure of location in general. So your comment is totally irrelevant.

Comment: @StubbornAtom so in my case is sample mean and sample median right?

Comment: Hence why I said bad measure and interquantiles and not interquantil range. Your comment literally adds nothing

Comment: Yeah sample mean and sample median.

Comment: @orange (Please use @) Whether the measure is bad or not is not the question. And there is no "interquantiles".

Comment: Stop @'ing me. I don't want to debate a random person online.